# php login/registration system ( password does not match )

Tags: php, mysql

here is my registration page:

```
<?php 
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>

<html>
<head>

<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if ( $_POST['registerbtn']){
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];



    if ($getuser){

        if ($getemail){

            if($getpass){

                if($getretypepass){

                    if($getpass === $getretypepass){


                        if((strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail,"@")) && (strstr($getemail,"."))) {
                            require("./connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                            if ($numrows == 0)
                            {
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                            if ($numrows == 0 )
                            {
                               // $password = md5($password);
                                $password = md5(md5("qwe".$password."qwe"));
                                $date = date("F d, Y");
                                $code = md5(rand());

                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$getuser','$password','$getemail','0','$code','$date')");

                                echo "Your acount has been created! You can log in here <a href=./login.php>Log in</a>";

                               // $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                              //  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                              //  if($numrows == 1 )
                              //  {
                                //   $site = "http://localhost/";
                                //   $webmaster = "Reem <ralsuhai@kent.edu>";
                                //   $headers = "From: $webmaster"; 
                                //   $subject = "Activate your account";
                               //    $message = "Thanks for registering. Click the link below to activate your account";
                                //   $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                //   $message .= "You must activate your account to login.";


                                //   if ( mail($getemail,$subject, $message, $headers));{


                                   //    $errormsg = "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activiation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
                                   //    $getuser = "";
                                    //   $getemail="";

                                      // }

                                    //else

                                  // $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your activation email was not sent.";

                                    //}

                                 //   else

                                  //  $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your acccount was not created";

                                }

                                else 

                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that Email."; 
                                }

                                else 

                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that username.";

                            mysql_close();

                            }

                        else

                       $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address to register";

                        }

                    else

                    $errormsg = "Your passwords did not match";


                    }

                    else

                    $errormsg = "You must retype your password to register.";



                }

                else

                $errormsg = "You must enter your password to register.";


            }


        else

            $errormsg = "You must enter your email to register.";

        }

    else 

        $errormsg = "You must enter your username to register.";

    }
else 

$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='pass' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Retype Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value=''/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register'/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>";


echo $form;

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my login.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>

<html>
<head>

<title> Login page </title>
</head>



<body>

<?php

if($username && $userid){
    echo "You are already looged in as <b>$username</b>. <a href=./customer_account.php>Click here</a>";

    }

else

{

$form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href='./register.php'>Register</a></td>
<td><a href='./forgetpass.php'>Forget your password?<a/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>";


if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($user)
    {
        if ($password)
        {
            require("connect.php");
            //$password = md5($password);
            $password = md5(md5("qwe".$password."qwe"));

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if ($numrows == 1)


            {
             $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
             $dbid = $row['id'];  
             $dbuser = $row['username']; 
             $dbpass = $row['password'];
             $dbactive = $row['active'];

             if ($password == $dbpass)
             {
                if($dbactive == 1)
                {
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;


                    echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='./customer_account.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page.";

                    }
                else 

                echo "you must activate your account to log in. $form";


                 }

                 else 

                    echo "You did not enter the correct password. $form";



                }

            else


              echo "The username you have entered was not found. $form";
            }
        else
        echo "You must enter your password. $form";

        }

        else
        echo "You must enter your username. $form";

    }

    else

    echo $form;
    }

?>


</body>


</html>
```

SQL table:

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `users`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

There is a problem in matching the two passwords, the one in the database and the one the user enters, the password is correct but it is not letting me enter and the error: "Your passwords did not match" appears.

Comment: There's so many things in this code that need fixing...But first, why are you using md5 twice?

Comment: I was trying to apply this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2NYbEjTzE8 and he said md5 twice will make it more secure.

Comment: Your question has too much (very messy) code.  You need to boil things down and clean them up to find your problem.  And if you don't find your problem, you'll then be in a better position to get help.

Comment: I made the same points that is mentioned in the tutorial, his code worked fine, but mine no.. I do not see any mistakes as I followed the video tutorial. May be you can see something that I can not see as a beginner.

Comment: @user3483167 So many if conditions... this is not a tutorial you should be following. It's way too messy, read this: http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/6102/how-create-login-page-phpmysql-using-pdo-query.html . And using md5 twice does not necessarily make it more secure. I mean for ffs, the guy in the YoutTube video didn't even show you how to filter $_POST values. Also read this: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5/. It's heavily documented so you'll learn better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin by echoing the variables $password and $dbpass. This will be a good start point. It may not be returning results to populate the $dbpass variable or there could be whitespace etc

Comment: Apologies, I didn't want to add as an answer, however current rep would not allow me to comment